# Is it possible to change the Mailing label format?

Tags: address-labels, mailing

I would like to change the way the mailing label prints. i.e.. remove the country, bring postcode down to next line etc. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Administer - Localization - Address Settings**, and the mailing label format is there for you to edit.  You can move, add, and remove tokes as needed.

(For reference, **Administer - Communications - Label Formats** handles the formatting of label size and arrangement on the sheet.)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to format parts of the address? Like right-aligning and changing font size on only parts of the adress?

Comment: It's all tokens, and tokens are usually only used in the context of HTML rendering, so it's possible that it might render HTML wrappers and their style attributes. It's also possible that it won't, or that it will only do so in some situations.  It's worth testing out, though.

Comment: HTML code directly in the settings field did not render correctly...:-(